# Autoplaying embedded Facebook videos in Qualtrics

Tags: html, facebook, video, autoplay

I have created a qualtrics survey containing an assortment of embedded videos from Facebook. The videos appear in the survey and work perfectly, but I need them to autoplay - currently, the participant has to manually click play.

I am using the embedded code from Facebook and copying into the 'HTML View' textbox on the questions in the survey.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcapitalismbethechange%2Fvideos%2F1825771414355523%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can add `&autoplay=true` to the `href` URL but it will be muted

Answer (score 0):

Add &autoplay=1 at the end of the URL.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDSouzaDinesh%2Fvideos%2F1650157581677557%2F&show_text=0&width=560&autoplay=1" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```